# Failed for the first time in the last unit of my graduation. What options do I have?

Tags: masters

I have failed the very last unit, which is my first fail for my combined degree course. I haven't failed any of the in-semester assessments, nor have I failed any other units in my course. I was curious as to what options I would have? The circumstance, I would say, are exceptional as it is the only  element that is holding me from graduation. I also haven't missed any of my classes.

Any advice would be highly appreciate it - if I can provide any information, please let me know.

Comment: Sorry to hear about your experience. This question is likely to be off-topic here because the answer is specific to your conditions and regulations of your university, and we don't know them. It's likely that you will be asked to repeat the unit and/or resit the assessment.

Comment: I appreciate how stressful this situation can be, and that just any advice is going to go a long way in making things feel more under control. But policies like this tend to be university independent, and so it's likely you'll need to (and should) discuss with your university staff to find the exact situation.

Comment: @Bilkokuya any advice would be highly appreciate it  - who would be the best point of contact would you say

Comment: @3kstc When I was in a similar situation - I spoke with my direct tutors, head of department and we had an office for dealing with exactly these kinds of things. At least somebody should be able to help find you the next person to speak to. Just don't be afraid of annoying people or approaching too many people - it's a serious situation for you, and worrying about badgering/annoying people should be the last of your concerns. In the end though, regardless of what happens - I feel it's important to say things will work out in the long run, even if the degree result isn't what you want.